# Replace text in paragraph with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For my app I have information from an API coming in, which is a bunch of text, put in between paragraph tags.  However, sometimes the text will say "null".  How do I remove any text which has "null" and replace it with "No info" with Javascript?  Similar to a swear filter.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```
all_string.replace('null', 'No Info');
```

[image]

In that way, you may trans words like *disannulling* will be turned into *disanNo Infoing*. So you should use regex to match the spec *null* word:

```
all_string.replace(/\bnull\b/g, 'No Info');
```

**Example**

```js
var element = document.querySelector('p');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/\bnull\b/g, 'No Info');
```

```html
<p>this is the first null line.
    
    another null null null.
    
    thisnull will not be replaced. </p>
```

Comment: What if I dont know the string name but I want to check all text in the body?

Comment: @JoshO'Connor You don't have to know the string name. `all_string` is just the name of the variable set by you. In this case, if you're using AJAX to get the string from some APIs, set the responseText to `all_string`. Sorry for my poor English, did I make myself clear?

Comment: It doesnt work... I am trying to replace everything in the  <p > tags, not a variable..

Comment: @JoshO'Connor Yea... The code replaced every *null*. You may refer to [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and I will update my answer to show an example.

Comment: Ok sounds good.  Im elbows deep in another project, I will definitely get back to it in a few days, and then I will upvote if correct... plz bear with me and be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

To replace text you can use the [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.

You can use it like this:

```
YOUR_STRING = YOUR_STRING.replace(/\bnull\b/g, "No info");
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/a9osg2zp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function.

If you want to replace multiples you will want to use regex.

For example,

`"hello hello".replace("hello","goodbye")`

Outputs: `"goodbye hello"`

`"hello hello".replace(/hello/g,"goodbye")`

Outputs: `"goodbye goodbye"`

Answer (score 0):

```js
while(APIString.indexOf('null') != -1){
  APIString.replace('null','No info');
}
```